# Initialize a countdown thread, then perform an action

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am working in C#, Silverlight.

I need a way to initialize a count down based on some value in seconds (or some other time unit) and at the end of the countdown I need to perform some method.

The countdown must be separate from the main application.

Comment: Backhround thread with a timer would do this, which bit are you struggling with?

Comment: Well the initialization of the thread and then starting the timer over on that thread.  Would i just create a new thread and make a new action to give to the thread which has the logic for the timer in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the System.Timers.Timer object. Subscribe to the Elapsed event and then call Start.

```
using System.Timers;
...
some method {
...
    Timer t = new Timer(duration);
    t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(handlerMethod);
    t.AutoReset = false;
    t.Start();
...
}

void handlerMethod(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

By default (as shown above), Timer will use `ThreadPool` to trigger the event(s). That means that handlerMethod will not be running on the same thread as your application. It may contest with other threads in the ThreadPool, but not with a thread outside the pool. You may set the SynchronizingObject to modify this behavior. In particular, if the Elapsed event invokes a method in a Windows Form control you must run on the same thread that created the control, setting SynchronizingObject to the control will accomplish this.

Comment: If you only want it to fire once (that seems to be the requirement here) make sure you stop it after it fires the first time.

Comment: how does this answer the "The countdown must be separate from the main application." statement in OP?

Comment: I'm assuming by "separate from the main application" they mean different thread.

Comment: This is close, but how do i get this method to run on a separate thread?

Comment: Note that .Net 4.5 offers Task.Delay, which simplifies the code a lot. See my answer for how to do this.

Comment: Jordan, using Task.Delay gets it on a separate thread as you requested. See my answer below.

Comment: This is bascially what i used except i went Thread newThread = new Thread(SomeMethod); where SomeMethod is { m_timer.start;}

Comment: @jordan.peoples Why would you create a new thread? The timer is already running in it's own thread and will not interfere with the thread that calls Start(). As an example, try this code: http://pastebin.com/319ba56E. As you can see, it keeps chugging along even while the Elapsed event is running.

Comment: You are semi right.  timer.start() does not create a dedicated thread, rather it will execute its tick function on some available thread.

Your original code sample is the correct way, but remember it doesn't explicitly create a thread just for the timer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Task.Delay`

```
static void SomeMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread ID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    Console.WriteLine("performing an action...");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int someValueInSeconds = 5;

    Console.WriteLine("Thread ID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(someValueInSeconds)).ContinueWith(t => SomeMethod());

    // Prevents the app from terminating before the task above completes
    Console.WriteLine("Countdown launched. Press a key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note that the only line of code you care about is the one with `Task.Delay`. I've included everything else to demonstrate that the action gets executed after the countdown, and on another thread, as you requested.

**Aviod** using the Timer class, the new Task.* APIs offer the same level of flexibility with much simpler code.

Comment: In my project i only have Task.WaitAny and Task.WaitAll

Answer (score 1):

While calling event handlers they should not be blocked, they should return immediately. You should implement this by a Timer, BackgroundWorker or Thread (in this order of preference).

Reference:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class MyForm : Form {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }

    Timer timer;
    MyForm() {
        timer = new Timer();
        count = 10;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing) {
            timer.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    int count;
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Text = "Wait for " + count + " seconds...";
        count--;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Timers.Timer doesnt have .tick

Comment: @jordan.peoples He's using System.Windows.Forms.Timer which does have a `Tick` event.

Comment: im trying to avoud using the System.Windows dll

Answer (score 1):

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

timer.Tick += delegate(object s, EventArgs args)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    // do your work here
                };

// 300 ms timer
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300); 
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Dont have access to DispatcherTimer.

and System.Timers.Timer doesnt have .tick

Comment: what version os silverlight are you using?

Comment: latest and greatest my friend

Comment: DispatcherTimer is supported in Silverlight 3,4, & 5. Do you have a reference to System.Windows.dll in your project (think that is where it is at). Also, add using System.Windows.Threading ...

Comment: Ah Rodger that , i am trying to avoid including that DLL